# Visual Studio UWP App target version: Missing new Windows builds (v2009 and higher)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, uwp

Today I was just testing around with VisualStudio (C++) and wanted to try an UWP App project (with DirectX12). On creating the project I got asked for the target Windows version and minimum supported Windows version for this UWP app. However the newest target version I can select is Windows 2004 (build 19041).

The own docs from MS also stop at this version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version?ocid=VSClient_VerX_NewProject_version

I have the newest WindowsSDK installed (10.0.19041) and it seems like there just isn't a new Version for Windows 2009 and newer (I've got 21H1 installed): https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/

So why is that so? I really don't get why there is no new WinSDK for the corresponding Windows builds and why the highest selectable target for UWP apps is 2004.
I guess it's fine, the UWP app runs on my 21H1 machine, but still confusing MS stuff... Or maybe I'm missing some info.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the webstie-[Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/), there is a note: Windows 10, version 21H1 is a scoped set of features for select performance improvements and quality enhancements. Developers should be aware of this release, but no action is necessary at this time.

A new Windows SDK will not be issued to accompany this version of Windows because this release doesn’t introduce new APIs. That means there’s no need to modify your project files or target a new version of Windows, and you should continue to use the Windows 10 SDK for Windows 10, version 2004. **When setting the target version for your Windows app, Windows 10 build 19041 is still the most recent target version**.

That's why you still need to select the build 19041 as the newest target version.

Answer (score -1):

It's missing because you don't need it. Windows 20H2 and higher don't make a huge change to the existing SDK, so until Windows 11 (aka 21H2) is released, there's no need to up your target version :)